# Dynamic destroying of views

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

In the following code, I am manually checking every view whether it has some content or it is empty. And if it has some content then i am destroying it. I don't want to check every view manually, I want a code that will select non-empty view  dynamically so that I can destroy that view and no need to check manually.And at a time there is only one non-empty view.

```
    function reset_container() {

        if (aasview != null) {
            aasview.destroy();
        }
        if (alewives != null) {
            alewives.destroy();
        }
        if (aa_amendview != null) {
            aa_amendview.destroy();
        }
        if (aa_dispatchview != null) {
            aa_view.destroy();
        }
        if (aa_postview != null) {
            aa_postview.destroy();
        }
        if (cc_dispatchview != null) {
            cc_dispatchview.destroy();
        }
        if (cc_postview != null) {
            cc_postview.destroy();
        }

        if (cm_salesview != null) {
            cm_salesview.destroy();
        }
        if(cc_view!=null){
            cc_view.destroy();
        }
        if (cc_amendview != null) {
            cc_amendview.destroy();
        }
        if (quotationview != null) {
            quotationview.destroy();
        }
        if(truckview!=null){
            truckview.destroy();
        }
        if (create_mnview != null) {  
            create_mnview.destroy();    
        }   
        if (create_stoview != null) {
            create_stoview.destroy();
        }
        if(vehicle_view != null){
            vehicle_view.destroy();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How are you creating the views? If they are in an aggregation (such as in a SplitApp master/detail pages or App pages) or even just in an array you could then simply loop over them to simplify your code:

e.g. Stored in array:

```
[view1, view2, view3].forEach(function(view) {
    if (view != null) {  //might not need this test depending on how you populate the array
        view.destroy();
    }
})
```

e.g. Stored in sap.m.SplitApp detailPages aggregation:

```
this.oRoot.getDetailPages().forEach(function(view) {
    view.destroy();
});
```

Hard to provide any specific details without any context to your code.  ;-) I'm not sure why you even need to destroy them?

Comment: They are not in an array. Each view is created differently. As I am  placing these different views on same container on selection of particular menu(header) item.

Comment: Use an array to store your views then as I've shown and Jasper_07 has give a great impl below....

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar and used a registry

to use

```
jQuery.sap.require("my.viewRegistry");
// create view via the registry
my.viewRegistry.createView('id', 'view.name', 'JS');

//access view
var oView = my.viewRegistry.getView('id');

//delete view 
my.viewRegistry.deleteView('id');

//delete all views
my.viewRegistry.setViews();
```

the code

```
jQuery.sap.declare("my.viewRegistry");

my.viewRegistry = {};

(function() {

  var _views = {}; // object that stores the view instances

 /**
  * Creates a view for the given data
  */
 my.viewRegistry.createView = function(sId, sName, sType) {
     // return view if already created
     if (my.viewRegistry.getView(sId)) {
         return my.viewRegistry.getView(sId);
     }
     //create view
     var oView = sap.ui.view({
         id: sId,
         viewName: sName,
         type: sType
     });
     //add view
     _views[sId] = oView;

     return oView;
 };

 /*
  * delete the view with the given id
  */
 my.viewRegistry.deleteView = function(sId) {
     delete _views[sId];
 };
 /*
  * get the view with the given id
  */
 my.viewRegistry.getView = function(sId) {
     return _views[sId];
 };

 /*
  * get all views
  */
 my.viewRegistry.getViews = function() {
     return _views;
 };

 /*
  * set views 
  */
 my.viewRegistry.setViews = function(oViews) {
     _views = oViews;
 };

}());
```